# Can you use futur antérieur tense to make a guess about a past event?

Tags: sens, temps-grammatical

- Ça les **aura** peut-être **fait** hésiter un peu. Et elle a pu en profiter pour les manipuler.

I thought that futur antérieur tense is equal to *will have done* in English and means *future perfect*.

But in this sentence, it does not make sense to think of this  futur antérieur tense as meaning a future event, because in the next sentence *a pu* means a past event.

So maybe, futur antérieur tense (perhaps, when used with *peut-être*) is used in this example to make a guess about a past event?

Comment: It is: might have made them hesitate a bit.

Answer (score 3):

The *futur antérieur* can have two different uses:

- Temporal function to express a completed future action:

  > *Je t'appellerai quand je serai arrivé*:
- Modal function to express probability or supposition in the past:

  > *Il n'est pas encore arrivé, il lui sera arrivé quelque chose*.

This is what is expressed in the sentence in your question.*

The use of the *futur antérieur* is enough to express probability, using an adverb to reinforce the degree of probability (*peut-être*, *certainement*, *sans (aucun) doute*...) is only optional.

If we compare with the use with the *passé composé*:

- *Ça les a peut-être fait hésiter un peu*. → *peut-être* is used to show the event is hypothetical.
- *Ça les aura fait hésiter un peu*.  →  the *futur antérieur* is used to the event is hypothetical.

We would use the *conditionnel passé* to show an even greater degree of uncertainty:

- *Ça les aurait fait hésiter un peu*.

in these last two sentences *peut-être* maybe just adding a little more doubts, maybe!

Further reference [Le futur antérieur de l’indicatif, niveau B2](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/le-futur-anterieur-de-lindicatif-niveau-b2.html)

*<sub>In English, this probability is expressed by a modal verb ("must" "might"...) (It must/might have made them hesitate).</sub>